# How to move metro UI back to my touch screen monitor?

Tags: windows-8

On a PC with one touch screen monitor and one non-touch monitor, occasionaly win 8 metro UI comes up on the non-touch monitor. How can a user force it to move back to the touchwithout restarting the PC?